# serious 404's, bulk redirects

Tags: html, web, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I have a bit of a situation coming up. Due to a complete website structure redesign that is basically inevetible, I expect to have our sitemap of about 12,000 url's have about 90-95% of them change. out of those 12,000, I expect around 5000-6000 internal links to go dead in the process. There are no external links to this site yet, as it is still in development.

is there a tool out there I can feed the sitemap.xml after the restructuring and have it parse each page for a 404 error, and only report the pages/errors?

I have found a few tools, but all of them seem to be limited to 100 pages.

any advice for an intermediate webmaster to help this situation? 301 redirects are not viable in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how experienced you are with programming, doing this shouldn't be hard (parse sitemap.xml, find all links, make http request to each, save status code).

If you are looking for a tool specifically, I would say you can try wget (feeding it the sitemap URL, see here for details: http://www.wezm.net/technical/2009/05/spider-a-site-with-wget-using-sitemap-xml/), or [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

Comment: trying that HTTrack tool; will see where that takes me, thanks!